# OpengGL es 2.0 render to texture with fully/partial and null transparency

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to render pictures with all kind of transparency unfortunately I can't figure out how to.

The rendered textures are created from OpenGL point-s and I set their transparency as desired. After it I apply blur on the texture. (without the blur it still looks similar)

If I render a texture with fully transparent background and using this setting `GLES20.GL_RGBA with GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` the partial transparent parts do not show. It looks like this (the black blobs)
[image]

If I use not fully transparent background in the rendered images, the pictures below the rendered image becomes pale, so there won't be fully transparent parts.

And if I use `GLES20.GL_RGB with GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5` there won't be transparency ofc, but I want it to look something like this but with transparency.

(This pictures are created from using the same code but with different render to texture settings so under the second picture there are those circles too.)

[image]

Comment: What is your `glBlendFunc`?

Comment: @mikkokoo I've tried these:  GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ZERO, GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: or are u using a Fragment shader?

Comment: @j-p yes I'm using a simple fragment shader this(the RGB values may be different):
`precision mediump float;
varying float v_ageFactor;
void main()
{
   gl_FragColor =  vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   gl_FragColor.a *= (v_ageFactor);
}`

Comment: @j-p I've tried those blendfuncs but currently they are disabled because I didn't achive my goal. So I should use this instead ?
`gl_FragColor =vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, v_ageFactor);`

Comment: what is v_ageFactor? (note:blend is still active after fragment processing, i was wrong). what texture are you sampling in the fragment shader? could you show your rendering function?

Comment: @j-p I don't use texture in fragment shader those blobs are essentially black GL_POINTS and the v_ageFactor is how transparent they should be

Comment: @j-p [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tug23pzpqtfnhut/SmokeTest001.java?dl=0)  bottom of the file renderToTexture() gets called in every draw cycle

Comment: Is your v_ageFactor out of the range (0..1)? Try `gl_FragColor = vec4(max(0.0, -v_ageFactor), max(0.0, v_ageFactor - 1.0), 0.0, v_ageFactor);` and see if you get any red (negative) or green (> 1.0).

Comment: @Justin it should've been but it's (0..3,5) good catch. I'll fix it when I get home, but could this cause this kind of behaviour?

Comment: @j-p yes I use it to blur the rendered texture but If I don't blur it. It is still shows the same pictures like above but more pixely. I create the original texture at drawRender() I pass a texture to the shader there but I don't use it(forgot to remove)

Comment: @Justin it didn't help :(

Comment: @Justin in the end your comment helped to solve it, it was a combination of that what you wrote, and that I set the rendered texture background white so when I blured it it overwhelmed the grey color and I used low values so the difference in the color did not show

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading those textures through the Android Bitmap class, your problem might be that Bitmap converts images into the pre-multiplied format which is not directly compatible with OpenGL ES blending.  You either have to avoid using Bitmap or reverse the pre-multiplication in your fragment shader code by dividing the RGB color channels by the Alpha.  There is more information in this [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1).

Comment: In the effect I want to apply to the screen (black blobs) I don't use textures. I create it with colored `GL_Points` and I vary the alpha value of this points. After it's done I render it to a texture than I put this texture on a screen sized rectangle. If there would be a problem with the other textures than it should only effect the areas where I use bitmaps as texture, shoudn't it? And it's not the case.